NGINX Config for SSL wrapped Proxy-Protocol v2
I am trying to use NGINX as a TCP reverse proxy to proxy connections received from the client. The workflow is as below:

Client creates a TCP connection with NGINX on port 443.
Client initiates a SSL handshake with NGINX.
Once the SSL handshake is complete, client creates a PROXY-PROTOCOL v2 header with the details of the server it intends to communicate with and sends it to NGINX.
Client then starts sending actual data to NGINX that must be forwarded to the server as mentioned in the ProxyProtocol header.

I was able to achieve this using the config below:

stream {

    log_format proxy_proto_log '$proxy_protocol_addr::$proxy_protocol_port - $proxy_protocol_server_addr::$proxy_protocol_server_port $proxy_protocol_tlv_0x05 $proxy_protocol_tlv_0x30 - [$time_local] '
                     '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                     '$session_time';

    log_format ssl_log '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                 '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                 '$ssl_protocol $ssl_server_name $ssl_session_id $ssl_session_reused'
                 '$session_time "$upstream_addr" '
                 '"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';

    server {
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.proxy.log  proxy_proto_log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.proxy.log info;

        listen 127.0.0.1:2000 proxy_protocol reuseport;
        proxy_protocol_timeout 60s;
        proxy_pass $proxy_protocol_server_addr:$proxy_protocol_server_port;
    }

    upstream some_backend {
         server 127.0.0.1:2000;
    }


    server {
        listen                443 ssl backlog=1024 reuseport;
        proxy_pass            some_backend;

        proxy_timeout         5400;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.ssl.log  ssl_log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.ssl.log info;  
        
        ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
   
    }
}


However as you can see the connection has to be proxied twice in NGINX. One connection is responsible for SSL termination and the other for PROXY-PROTOCOL v2. If we try to add proxy_protocol in the listen directive of 443 the SSL handshake at client fails as NGINX expects to receive the Proxy-Protocol v2 header. Any thoughts how this could be achieved without creating the intermediate proxy connection just for SSL termination? Any help would be appreciated. I understand this may not be standard but changing the client application is not feasible, hence trying to see if we can optimize the NGINX config without making any changes on client.
Tried below NGINX config which did not work as NGINX was parsing PROXY-PROTOCOL header before SSL termination:
server {
        listen                443 ssl proxy_protocol backlog=1024 reuseport;
        proxy_pass            some_backend;

        proxy_timeout         5400;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.ssl.log  ssl_log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.ssl.log info;  
        
        ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
   
    }

